# How to create a device with buttons that records when they are pressed

Tags: led, usb, timers

I want to build a very simple device, which has a bunch of buttons for switching "settings" and LED lights to show which "setting" it is on.  I also want it to record the times of the transitions between settings so that I can later connect it to a computer through USB and retrieve the timestamps of the setting changes, i.e. when the buttons were pressed.

What is the best way to do this?  Is it with Arduino or some other way?  If it is with Arduino, what would I need to buy, and what would I need to read?

Comment: What research have you done? Code?

Answer (score 2):

Arduino is ideal for it. Buy Arduino or Genuino UNO with Starter Kit. Starter kits contain buttons, LEDs, resistors, breadboard and example projects brochure.

link: [Getting Started with Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage)

Answer (score 2):

All is reasonably easy.

- Buttons: use separate buttons, or think about a small 4x4 matrix keypad.
- LED: WS8212 etc or use your own separate LEDs (very cheap)
- Record times: store them on a SD card
- USB: It is possible to send texts via USART which can connect via USB; also you can consider putting the SD card directly in your computer.